# Multiple upload files from file list in User computer to server in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

pe someone can help me on this. 
I've been googling & searching a lot regarding this issue. 
I'm working on web application where I need to :

1. Click a button to get a folder/directory of files - Done with
   javascript
2. Get list of available files is the selected folder/directory - Done
   with javascript
3. Start uploading those file in the **list** into server folder - **Failed!**

As I understand my limitation so far :

- I cannot programmatically assign a value to asp:FileUpload control -
  readOnly
- I cannot access those file in the list in FileInfo/FileStream - it's fail as it can't find the source file given from the list due to it's not
  came from server directory
  came from server directory
- I cannot simply try to use File.Copy to upload the file - it's fail as it can't find the source file given from the list due to it's not
  came from server directory

I've been getting error :

> "Could not find a part of the path"

List of files in the folder, example :

- File1.pdf
- File2.png
- File3.txt
- File4.xls
- File5.jpg

While in the server, I already create a folder named as "Temp" ***but the problem actually because system can't recognize the path of those file in the list***.

This is part of my code :

```
string strPath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Sample";
string strListedFiles = txtList.InnerText.ToString();
string[] strFiles = strListedFiles.split(new Char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string strFile in strFiles)
{
FileInfo fiFile = new FileInfo(strPath.ToString() + "\\" + strFile.Trim());
FileStream fsFile = fiFile.OpenRead(); //Failed at here
...
...
...
...
}
```

Comment: You can use webclient method to upload files. Assign each file programmatically one by one to webclient to PUT it on server. Refer link for webclient code http://chiragvidani.blogspot.in/2011/10/how-to-uploaddownload-file-tofrom.html

Comment: Sir, I use WebClient method shown in the link given but still got error. "An exception occurred during a WebClient request" which lead to "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Sample\File1.pdf'"... Seems like still back to the same issue where system cannot retrieve the file given in string(which is populated as array  of string from list). What is wrong with retrieving the file from string???

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something [which has been shown with demo in this tutorial.](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxFileManagerAndUploadDemos/UploadControl/MultiFileSelection.aspx)
This will allow you to upload multiple files concurrently.

[Another alternative example with jQuery MultiFile is given here.](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/12/aspnet-upload-multiple-files-using.html)

Comment: 1st link seems like the answer but let me test it out first. 2nd link already used before but this time the requirement is "a quick bulk upload" where the 2nd link will need user to select file by file before upload. The requirement is select a folder/directory as I mention above but what is shown in 1st link can be used too. Thanks for the link.

Comment: 1st link give great solution but it came with some cost, is there any other way to make my code working?